# Proving positive definiteness or semi-definiteness of a matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I have the following 4x4 real symmetric matrix:

$K=\begin{bmatrix}3-3w & -\frac{4}{3}+a+2w & \frac{5}{12}+b-\frac{w}{2} & 0\\
-\frac{4}{3}+a+2w & -1-6a-3x & \frac{3}{4}+3a-3b+2x-\frac{y}{2} & -\frac{2}{3}-a-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{z}{2}\\
\frac{5}{12}+b-\frac{w}{2} & \frac{3}{4}+3a-3b+2x-\frac{y}{2} & -\frac{1}{2}+6b & \frac{19}{12}-b+\frac{y}{2}-2z\\
0 & -\frac{2}{3}-a-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{z}{2} & \frac{19}{12}-b+\frac{y}{2}-2z & -3+3z
\end{bmatrix}$

```
K = 
  {{3 - 3 w, -4/3 + a + 2 w, 5/12 + b - w/2, 0},
   {-4/3 + a + 2 w, -1 - 6 a - 3 x, 3/4 + 3 a - 3 b + 2 x - y/2, -2/3 - a - 
      x/2 + z/2},
   {5/12 + b - w/2, 3/4 + 3 a - 3 b + 2 x - y/2, -1/2 + 6 b, 19/12 -b + 
      y/2 - 2 z},
   {0, -2/3 - a - x/2 + z/2, 19/12 - b + y/2 - 2 z, -3 + 3 z}};
```

It has six unknown variables: $a,b,w,x,y$ and $z$ where $w,x,y,z$ must be positive real numbers. $a$ and $b$ are real numbers.

I need to determine the set of values of the above unknown variables for which the matrix $K$ is positive definite or semi-definite, or show that there are NO values of the unknowns for which the matrix $K$ is positive definite or positive semi-definite.

For the real symmetric matrix $K$:

- It is positive definite if all its leading principal
  minors are positive.
- It is positive semi-definite if all its principal minors are non-negative.

To determine the values for positive definiteness of $K$, I tried:

```
cond1 = K[[1,1]];
cond2 = Minors[K[[1;;3,1;;3]]][[1,1]];
cond3 = Minors[K][[1,1]];
cond4 = Det[K];
bounds = 
  Simplify[
    Reduce[
      cond1 > 0 && cond2 > 0 && cond3 > 0 && cond4 > 0 && 
        w > 0 && x > 0 && y > 0 && z > 0,
      {a, b, w, x, y, z}, Reals]]
```

It does not yield any results even after running *Mathematica* for more than an hour. It would be of great help to me if you could suggest a way of formulating the above problem in a manner such that *Mathematica* is able to evaluate the values.

Comment: well this is a bit silly but `Map[#>0&,Eigenvalues[K] // FullSimplify // ToRadicals]`

Comment: The dimensions of your matrix are $3\times 4$ because you omitted a comma. Also, just a warning: You shouldn't use capital letters as variable names. `K` is a built-in symbol that's reserved for other uses.

Comment: @Jens: Thanks for pointing that out. I am new to _Mathematica_ and will keep it in mind.

Comment: Probably too slow to be practical, but here is another formulation that avoid roots/radicals. `cpol = CharacteristicPolynomial[kmat, t];
Resolve[ForAll[t, And @@ {w > 0, x > 0, y > 0, z > 0}, 
  Implies[cpol == 0, t >= 0]], Reals]`

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work.

```
kmat = {{3 - 3 w, -4/3 + a + 2 w, 5/12 + b - w/2, 
    0}, {-4/3 + a + 2 w, -1 - 6 a - 3 x, 
    3/4 + 3 a - 3 b + 2 x - y/2, -2/3 - a - x/2 + z/2}, {5/12 + b - 
     w/2, 3/4 + 3 a - 3 b + 2 x - y/2, -1/2 + 6 b, 
    19/12 - b + y/2 - 2 z}, {0, -2/3 - a - x/2 + z/2, 
    19/12 - b + y/2 - 2 z, -3 + 3 z}};
vec = Array[t, Length[kmat]];
prod = Expand[vec.kmat.vec]

(* Out[22]= 3 t[1]^2 - 3 w t[1]^2 - 8/3 t[1] t[2] + 2 a t[1] t[2] + 
 4 w t[1] t[2] - t[2]^2 - 6 a t[2]^2 - 3 x t[2]^2 + 5/6 t[1] t[3] + 
 2 b t[1] t[3] - w t[1] t[3] + 3/2 t[2] t[3] + 6 a t[2] t[3] - 
 6 b t[2] t[3] + 4 x t[2] t[3] - y t[2] t[3] - t[3]^2/2 + 
 6 b t[3]^2 - 4/3 t[2] t[4] - 2 a t[2] t[4] - x t[2] t[4] + 
 z t[2] t[4] + 19/6 t[3] t[4] - 2 b t[3] t[4] + y t[3] t[4] - 
 4 z t[3] t[4] - 3 t[4]^2 + 3 z t[4]^2 *)


Resolve[
 ForAll[Evaluate[vec], And @@ {w > 0, x > 0, y > 0, z > 0}, 
  prod >= 0], Reals]

(* Out[26]= (w <= 1 || x <= 0 || y <= 0 || z <= 0) && (w != 1 || 
   a + 2 w == 4/3 || x <= 0 || y <= 0 || z <= 0) && (w != 1 || 
   x <= 0 || 2 a + x <= -(1/3) || y <= 0 || 
   z <= 0) && (2 b - w == -(5/6) || w != 1 || x <= 0 || y <= 0 || 
   z <= 0) && (w >= 1 || w <= 0 || x <= 0 || 
   46 a + 3 a^2 - 25 w - 42 a w + 12 w^2 + 27 x - 27 w x <= -(43/3) ||
    y <= 0 || z <= 0) && (w >= 1 || w <= 0 || x <= 0 || 
   46 a + 3 a^2 - 25 w - 42 a w + 12 w^2 + 27 x - 27 w x != -(43/3) ||
    y <= 0 || -103 a + 92 b + 12 a b + 45 w + 102 a w - 84 b w - 
     12 w^2 - 72 x + 72 w x + 18 y - 18 w y == 101/3 || 
   z <= 0) && (w >= 1 || w <= 0 || x <= 0 || 
   46 a + 3 a^2 - 25 w - 42 a w + 12 w^2 + 27 x - 27 w x != -(43/3) ||
    y <= 0 || 2 a + x - z == -(4/3) || z <= 0) && (w >= 1 || 
   w <= 0 || -206 b + 12 b^2 - 23 w + 204 b w + 3 w^2 <= -(241/12) || 
   x <= 0 || 
   46 a + 3 a^2 - 25 w - 42 a w + 12 w^2 + 27 x - 27 w x != -(43/3) ||
    y <= 0 || z <= 0) && (w >= 1 || w <= 0 || x <= 0 || 
   46 a + 3 a^2 - 25 w - 42 a w + 12 w^2 + 27 x - 27 w x >= -(43/3) ||
    y <= 0 || -1080 a - 3456 a^2 - 1872 b - 6048 a b - 2592 b^2 - 
     93 w + 1764 a w + 3456 a^2 w + 4248 b w + 5616 a b w + 
     2160 b^2 w + 108 w^2 - 648 a w^2 - 2592 b w^2 - 893 x - 
     4944 a x - 3000 b x + 576 a b x + 432 b^2 x + 1332 w x + 
     4896 a w x + 3312 b w x - 468 w^2 x - 1728 x^2 + 1728 w x^2 + 
     404 y + 1236 a y - 1104 b y - 144 a b y - 540 w y - 1224 a w y + 
     1008 b w y + 144 w^2 y + 864 x y - 864 w x y - 108 y^2 + 
     108 w y^2 >= -6 || z <= 0) && (a >= 0 || w != 1 || x <= 0 || 
   2 a + x != -(1/3) || 6 a - 6 b + 4 x - y == -(3/2) || y <= 0 || 
   z <= 0) && (a >= 0 || w != 1 || x <= 0 || 2 a + x != -(1/3) || 
   y <= 0 || 2 a + x - z == -(4/3) || z <= 0) && (a >= 0 || w != 1 || 
   x <= 0 || 2 a + x >= -(1/3) || y <= 0 || 
   6 a + 36 a^2 + 6 b + 72 a b + 36 b^2 + 6 x + 48 a x + 24 b x + 
     16 x^2 - 3 y - 12 a y + 12 b y - 8 x y + y^2 <= -(1/4) || 
   z <= 0) && (a >= 0 || b >= 1/12 || w != 1 || x <= 0 || 
   2 a + x != -(1/3) || y <= 0 || z <= 0) && (w >= 1 || w <= 0 || 
   x <= 0 || 
   46 a + 3 a^2 - 25 w - 42 a w + 12 w^2 + 27 x - 27 w x >= -(43/3) ||
    y <= 0 || -1080 a - 3456 a^2 - 1872 b - 6048 a b - 2592 b^2 - 
     93 w + 1764 a w + 3456 a^2 w + 4248 b w + 5616 a b w + 
     2160 b^2 w + 108 w^2 - 648 a w^2 - 2592 b w^2 - 893 x - 
     4944 a x - 3000 b x + 576 a b x + 432 b^2 x + 1332 w x + 
     4896 a w x + 3312 b w x - 468 w^2 x - 1728 x^2 + 1728 w x^2 + 
     404 y + 1236 a y - 1104 b y - 144 a b y - 540 w y - 1224 a w y + 
     1008 b w y + 144 w^2 y + 864 x y - 864 w x y - 108 y^2 + 
     108 w y^2 != -6 || z <= 0 || 
   1134 a - 504 a^2 + 24 b - 504 a b - 770 w - 918 a w + 612 a^2 w + 
     264 b w + 504 a b w + 408 w^2 - 72 a w^2 - 288 b w^2 + 637 x - 
     741 a x - 372 b x + 36 a b x - 603 w x + 738 a w x + 396 b w x - 
     36 w^2 x - 216 x^2 + 216 w x^2 + 244 y + 660 a y + 36 a^2 y - 
     372 w y - 612 a w y + 144 w^2 y + 378 x y - 378 w x y - 587 z - 
     1899 a z - 144 a^2 z - 276 b z - 36 a b z + 1065 w z + 
     1710 a w z + 252 b w z - 540 w^2 z - 1080 x z + 1080 w x z - 
     54 y z + 54 w y z == -410) && (w >= 1 || w <= 0 || x <= 0 || 
   46 a + 3 a^2 - 25 w - 42 a w + 12 w^2 + 27 x - 27 w x >= -(43/3) ||
    y <= 0 || -1080 a - 3456 a^2 - 1872 b - 6048 a b - 2592 b^2 - 
     93 w + 1764 a w + 3456 a^2 w + 4248 b w + 5616 a b w + 
     2160 b^2 w + 108 w^2 - 648 a w^2 - 2592 b w^2 - 893 x - 
     4944 a x - 3000 b x + 576 a b x + 432 b^2 x + 1332 w x + 
     4896 a w x + 3312 b w x - 468 w^2 x - 1728 x^2 + 1728 w x^2 + 
     404 y + 1236 a y - 1104 b y - 144 a b y - 540 w y - 1224 a w y + 
     1008 b w y + 144 w^2 y + 864 x y - 864 w x y - 108 y^2 + 
     108 w y^2 <= -6 || z <= 0 || 
   20832 a + 28224 a^2 + 20832 b + 56448 a b + 28224 b^2 - 6848 w - 
     25680 a w - 27072 a^2 w - 42816 b w - 52416 a b w - 
     25344 b^2 w + 3328 w^2 + 6144 a w^2 + 144 a^2 w^2 + 
     24576 b w^2 + 1152 a b w^2 + 2304 b^2 w^2 + 14500 x + 
     41520 a x + 26208 b x - 4032 a b x - 4032 b^2 x - 19000 w x - 
     41160 a w x - 29952 b w x - 2016 a b w x - 1152 b^2 w x + 
     4800 w^2 x + 144 a w^2 x + 576 b w^2 x + 15505 x^2 + 984 b x^2 + 
     144 b^2 x^2 - 15540 w x^2 - 1008 b w x^2 + 36 w^2 x^2 + 256 y - 
     3024 a y - 4032 a^2 y + 12288 b y - 4032 a b y - 1504 w y + 
     4608 a w y + 4896 a^2 w y - 8832 b w y + 5760 a b w y + 
     1536 w^2 y - 576 a w^2 y - 2304 b w^2 y - 3904 x y - 
     5928 a x y - 3840 b x y + 288 a b x y + 4176 w x y + 
     5904 a w x y + 4032 b w x y - 288 w^2 x y - 1728 x^2 y + 
     1728 w x^2 y + 2560 y^2 + 3072 a y^2 + 144 a^2 y^2 - 
     3072 w y^2 - 2880 a w y^2 + 576 w^2 y^2 + 1728 x y^2 - 
     1728 w x y^2 - 11132 z - 42384 a z - 25344 a^2 z - 25248 b z - 
     52416 a b z - 27072 b^2 z + 20840 w z + 43896 a w z + 
     21888 a^2 w z + 44544 b w z + 46368 a b w z + 21888 b^2 w z - 
     10944 w^2 z - 5616 a w^2 z - 22464 b w^2 z - 26110 x z - 
     35616 a x z - 22608 b x z + 5760 a b x z + 4896 b^2 x z + 
     30360 w x z + 35136 a w x z + 25632 b w x z - 4536 w^2 x z - 
     13824 x^2 z + 13824 w x^2 z - 3520 y z - 3816 a y z - 
     1152 a^2 y z - 14592 b y z - 2016 a b y z + 5712 w y z + 
     2448 a w y z + 13248 b w y z - 2592 w^2 y z - 1728 y^2 z + 
     1728 w y^2 z + 8017 z^2 + 25440 a z^2 + 2304 a^2 z^2 + 
     6360 b z^2 + 1152 a b z^2 + 144 b^2 z^2 - 15156 w z^2 - 
     22464 a w z^2 - 5616 b w z^2 + 8100 w^2 z^2 + 13824 x z^2 - 
     13824 w x z^2 + 1728 y z^2 - 1728 w y z^2 >= -3844) && (w >= 1 ||
    w <= 0 || x <= 0 || 
   46 a + 3 a^2 - 25 w - 42 a w + 12 w^2 + 27 x - 27 w x != -(43/3) ||
    y <= 0 || 
   z <= 0 || -3432 a + 1008 b - 2016 a b - 2016 b^2 + 1342 w + 
     3324 a w - 1008 b w + 2448 a b w + 2016 b^2 w - 408 w^2 + 
     72 a w^2 + 288 b w^2 - 2495 x - 744 b x + 144 b^2 x + 2460 w x + 
     720 b w x + 36 w^2 x + 280 y - 1236 a y + 672 b y + 144 a b y - 
     144 w y + 1224 a w y - 576 b w y - 144 w^2 y - 864 x y + 
     864 w x y + 216 y^2 - 216 w y^2 + 1375 z + 4944 a z - 1944 b z - 
     576 a b z - 144 b^2 z - 1884 w z - 4896 a w z + 1584 b w z + 
     540 w^2 z + 3456 x z - 3456 w x z - 864 y z + 864 w y z != 
    958 || -189216 b + 4966272 b^2 - 290304 b^3 + 53605 w + 
     532608 b w - 9812448 b^2 w - 69120 b^3 w + 20736 b^4 w - 
     19104 w^2 - 503280 b w^2 + 4841856 b^2 w^2 + 352512 b^3 w^2 - 
     6876 w^3 + 159840 b w^3 + 5184 b^2 w^3 + 1296 w^4 - 54948 y + 
     598320 b y - 388800 b^2 y + 20736 b^3 y + 117876 w y - 
     1196208 b w y + 741312 b^2 w y - 20736 b^3 w y - 71136 w^2 y + 
     603072 b w^2 y - 352512 b^2 w^2 y + 8208 w^3 y - 5184 b w^3 y - 
     8676 y^2 + 88992 b y^2 - 5184 b^2 y^2 + 18612 w y^2 - 
     177120 b w y^2 + 5184 b^2 w y^2 - 11232 w^2 y^2 + 
     88128 b w^2 y^2 + 1296 w^3 y^2 + 161711 z - 1201776 b z - 
     4624992 b^2 z + 628992 b^3 z - 20736 b^4 z - 338472 w z + 
     2240352 b w z + 9217152 b^2 w z - 622080 b^3 w z + 
     191016 w^2 z - 883008 b w^2 z - 4593024 b^2 w^2 z - 
     12960 w^3 z - 155520 b w^3 z - 1296 w^4 z + 69408 y z - 
     711936 b y z + 41472 b^2 y z - 148896 w y z + 1416960 b w y z - 
     41472 b^2 w y z + 89856 w^2 y z - 705024 b w^2 y z - 
     10368 w^3 y z - 138816 z^2 + 1423872 b z^2 - 82944 b^2 z^2 + 
     297792 w z^2 - 2833920 b w z^2 + 82944 b^2 w z^2 - 
     179712 w^2 z^2 + 1410048 b w^2 z^2 + 20736 w^3 z^2 <= 
    28920) && (w >= 1 || 
   w <= 0 || -206 b + 12 b^2 - 23 w + 204 b w + 3 w^2 != -(241/12) || 
   x <= 0 || 
   46 a + 3 a^2 - 25 w - 42 a w + 12 w^2 + 27 x - 27 w x != -(43/3) ||
    y <= 0 || z <= 0 || 2 b - y + 4 z == 19/6) && (w >= 1 || 
   w <= 0 || -206 b + 12 b^2 - 23 w + 204 b w + 3 w^2 != -(241/12) || 
   x <= 0 || 
   46 a + 3 a^2 - 25 w - 42 a w + 12 w^2 + 27 x - 27 w x != -(43/3) ||
    y <= 0 || z >= 1 || z <= 0) && (w >= 1 || w <= 0 || x <= 0 || 
   46 a + 3 a^2 - 25 w - 42 a w + 12 w^2 + 27 x - 27 w x >= -(43/3) ||
    y <= 0 || -1080 a - 3456 a^2 - 1872 b - 6048 a b - 2592 b^2 - 
     93 w + 1764 a w + 3456 a^2 w + 4248 b w + 5616 a b w + 
     2160 b^2 w + 108 w^2 - 648 a w^2 - 2592 b w^2 - 893 x - 
     4944 a x - 3000 b x + 576 a b x + 432 b^2 x + 1332 w x + 
     4896 a w x + 3312 b w x - 468 w^2 x - 1728 x^2 + 1728 w x^2 + 
     404 y + 1236 a y - 1104 b y - 144 a b y - 540 w y - 1224 a w y + 
     1008 b w y + 144 w^2 y + 864 x y - 864 w x y - 108 y^2 + 
     108 w y^2 != -6 || z <= 0 || 
   504 a - 284 w - 456 a w + 36 a^2 w + 144 w^2 + 300 x - 36 a x - 
     300 w x + 36 a w x - 9 x^2 + 9 w x^2 - 148 z - 516 a z - 
     36 a^2 z + 276 w z + 468 a w z - 144 w^2 z - 306 x z + 
     306 w x z - 9 z^2 + 9 w z^2 >= -156) && (a >= 0 || w != 1 || 
   x <= 0 || 2 a + x >= -(1/3) || y <= 0 || 
   6 a + 36 a^2 + 6 b + 72 a b + 36 b^2 + 6 x + 48 a x + 24 b x + 
     16 x^2 - 3 y - 12 a y + 12 b y - 8 x y + y^2 != -(1/4) || 
   z <= 0 || -162 a + 72 a^2 - 24 b + 72 a b - 73 x + 84 a x + 
     36 b x + 24 x^2 - 20 y - 84 a y - 42 x y + 39 z + 252 a z + 
     36 b z + 120 x z + 6 y z == 26) && (a >= 0 || w != 1 || x <= 0 ||
    2 a + x >= -(1/3) || y <= 0 || 
   6 a + 36 a^2 + 6 b + 72 a b + 36 b^2 + 6 x + 48 a x + 24 b x + 
     16 x^2 - 3 y - 12 a y + 12 b y - 8 x y + y^2 >= -(1/4) || 
   z <= 0 || -828 a - 1296 a^2 - 432 b - 3024 a b - 1728 b^2 - 
     500 x - 1830 a x - 912 b x - 72 a b x - 645 x^2 - 36 b x^2 + 
     8 y + 48 a y + 216 a^2 y - 672 b y + 288 a b y + 156 x y + 
     252 a x y + 144 b x y + 72 x^2 y - 96 y^2 - 144 a y^2 - 
     72 x y^2 + 264 z + 1962 a z + 1080 a^2 z + 720 b z + 
     2808 a b z + 1728 b^2 z + 990 x z + 1584 a x z + 792 b x z + 
     576 x^2 z + 108 y z + 252 a y z + 720 b y z + 72 y^2 z - 
     189 z^2 - 1296 a z^2 - 324 b z^2 - 576 x z^2 - 72 y z^2 <= 
    96) && (a >= 0 || b != 1/12 || w != 1 || x <= 0 || 
   2 a + x != -(1/3) || y <= 0 || z <= 0 || 
   2 b - y + 4 z == 19/6) && (a >= 0 || w != 1 || x <= 0 || 
   2 a + x >= -(1/3) || y <= 0 || 
   6 a + 36 a^2 + 6 b + 72 a b + 36 b^2 + 6 x + 48 a x + 24 b x + 
     16 x^2 - 3 y - 12 a y + 12 b y - 8 x y + y^2 != -(1/4) || 
   z <= 0 || -200 a + 12 a^2 - 100 x + 12 a x + 3 x^2 + 28 z + 
     204 a z + 102 x z + 3 z^2 <= 92/3) && (a >= 0 || b != 1/12 || 
   w != 1 || x <= 0 || 2 a + x != -(1/3) || y <= 0 || z >= 1 || 
   z <= 0) && (a >= 0 || b == 1/12 || w != 1 || x <= 0 || 
   2 a + x != -(1/3) || y <= 0 || z <= 0 || 
   51 a - 18 b + 36 a b + 36 b^2 + 35 x + 12 b x - 5 y + 18 a y - 
     12 b y + 12 x y - 3 y^2 - 15 z - 72 a z + 36 b z - 48 x z + 
     12 y z != -(41/4) || -33 b + 2124 b^2 + 144 b^3 - 19 y + 
     240 b y - 144 b^2 y - 3 y^2 + 36 b y^2 + 58 z - 528 b z - 
     2016 b^2 z + 24 y z - 288 b y z - 48 z^2 + 576 b z^2 <= 145/12) *)
```

Caveat: I do not know offhand how to do a sanity check on this result. (If I claimed to know, I'd probably need a sanity check on myself.)

Comment: Thanks for spending time on this! `And @@ {w > 0, x > 0, y > 0, z > 0}` in the `Resolve` command does not seem to enforce the constraint that $w,x,y,z$ must be positive. On the same lines, I tried `Resolve[
 ForAll[Evaluate[vec], w > 0 && x > 0 && y > 0 && z > 0 &&
  prod >= 0], Reals]`, which seems to do much better but they all essentially provide the result that has a condition that equals `Det[kmat] > 0`, which is a non-linear algebraic equation of degree 4 and it is difficult to make sense out of it.

Comment: With this approach, the problem seems to boil down to solving non-linear algebraic equations simultaneously.

Comment: Over the reals,no less. One can try `GenericCylindricalDecomposition[res, {a, b, w, x, y, z}]` where `res` is the result of that `Resolve`. But that brought my laptop to its knees and I had to kill the kernel.

Comment: Thanks Daniel! One set of values that makes all the elements of the matrix zero and essentially proves semi-definiteness are `{w->1,x->1,y->1,z->1,a->-2/3,b->1/12}`. I haven't been able to workout anything for definiteness.